# Python ValueError abs of an array

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to python and have been unable to figure out how to fix this.  I am trying to do an iteration for each value in the array, and return the array of final values.  e is a user-input single value, while M is an array of varying length. I am trying to loop the iteration for each value of E until it closely solves Kepler's equation, M=E-e*sin(E), and then return the finished array of each E for given M.

```
def eccano(e, M):
   E=M
   for i in range(0,len(M)):
       while abs(E-e*sin(E)-M[i]) > 10**(-4):
           E=E-((E-e*sin(E)-M[i])/(1-e*cos(E)))
   return E

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ME.py", line 7, in eccano
    while abs(E-e*sin(E)-M[i]) > 10**(-4):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to fix? What do you expect this piece of code to do? (Consider that you will be much better off asking a specific question than just asking for advice.)

Comment: Since `E=M`, have you tried using `E[i]`? `while abs(E[i]-e*sin(E[i])-M[i]) > 10**(-4): ...`

Comment: What are the types and shapes of e and M?

Comment: Although it's orthogonal to the question, for anyone who's curious, I recognize what the OP is trying to do: solve Kepler's equation for the eccentric anomaly.  (Being a recovering astronomer had to come in handy eventually..)

Comment: As the traceback says "Use a.any() or a.all()",  for example iterate as long as at least one value is above 1e-4: np.any(np.abs(E-e*sin(E)-M[i]) > 10**(-4)):...  numpy cannot read your mind whether you want any or all, so it doesn't guess.

Comment: Adding E[i] gives the error "'tuple' object does not support item assignment".  I am inputting a single value for e, and an array for M of varying length. I am trying to iterate for each value of E (beginning with E=M) until it closely solves Kepler's equation (until abs(E-e*sin(E)-M[i]) < 10**(-4)) and then return the resulting E array.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're actually trying to do, but the problem is this:

```
while abs(E-e*sin(E)-M[i]) > 10**(-4):
```

All of those operations in the abs() work elementwise in numpy arrays, so you're doing some things that end with an array, taking the absolute value of every element in that array, then comparing to 10**(-4) and ending up with an array of booleans.  It's complaining that it can't evaluate that as "True" or "False" because it's an array that probably contains both True and False values.

Comment: e is a user-input single value, while M is an array of varying length.  I am trying to loop the iteration for each value of E until it closely solves Kepler's equation, M=E-e*sin(E) (@DSM was correct in noting my intentions), and then return the finished array of each E for given M.  
I hope this helps--forgive any wrong language, I am in the process of teaching myself python!

Comment: ok, now that finals are over I looked at the OP a little more closely, and I think I'm close to getting what you're trying to do; this is using Newton's method to solve E-e*sin(E) = M, right?  Is it that you have multiple M and you want to return an array E such that each E corresponds to an M, or is there something else going on that I'm not getting?

Answer (score 0):

`Abs` returns the type it is given, so you have to either select `E[i]`, use an operation such as sum, or just have for i in E.
For example:

```
abs(np.array([-1, 2, -4])) = array([1, 2, 4])
```

Assuming you want the 2-norm of `abs(E-e*sin(E)-M[i])` to be greater than `10^-4`, you'd write:

```
np.linalg.norm(abs(E-e*sin(E)-M[i]),2) > 10**(-4)
```

If you are looking for something else in the loop conditional add a little more info. Right now it's not really possible to infer what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an implementation of the [Newton–Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method). I can't give specific help, because I don't know what the function is, but here's how I would code the example in the Wikipedia page:

```
import numpy as np

def newtons(start_value, threshold):
   x = start_value

   stop = False
   while stop == False:
      x_previous = x
      # x -= function / first derivative of function
      x -= (np.cos(x) - x**3 )/ (-np.sin(x) - 3 * x**2)

      if np.abs(x - x_previous) < threshold:
         stop = True

   return x


print newtons(0.5, 0.0001)
```

Let us know if this is what you are trying to do, what e and M are, and what the specific function is.